# How to detect failure/error in a test script programmatically in QTP

Tags: qtp

Lets say there is a defect in a program execution in any language like java or c#, we have exception handling mechanism through which we can programmatically know that there is an error and in case we want to make a log of it we can store it in a txt or xls file.

In QTP, if i'm executing ten scripts and two scripts have failed and i want to make a log of the failed files in xls file, then how do i go about it? because it seems there is no mechanism programmatically through which i can detect that an error has occurred and a entry in the log accordingly. how do i approach this? ( by the way, i do not want to know about recovery scenario, because i'm not interested in handling the error but i'm interested in only detecting the error and making a note of it)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

QTP scripts are based on VBScript, the equivalent of exceptions in VBScript is `On Error` which is [described here](http://ss64.com/vb/onerror.html) (among [other places](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/08/19/error-handling-in-vbscript-part-one.aspx)).

However I don't see why you need this, if a test fails this fact gets logged in the run-report, can't you look in the default reports to see which test failed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My plan is to make a log of the errors in the xls file then add some extra details and then upload the defects in QC

Answer (score -1):

QTP 10 has recovery scenarios where you can call a function on error in test script. My idea here is to write a vbs function that creates and updates excel with error information. With function call you can even do more like sending mail or sms on error.

For understanding recovery scenarios, following link may be helpful to you

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_recovery_scenarios.htm